# Draw 2D face with 3D vertices

Tags: math, rotation, trigonometry, face

Please bear with me as I've *never* dealt with anything relating to this and I've been sitting on this issue for the last **two weeks**.

I'm developing a program that reads in faces from a 3D model. Each face is drawn by connecting a series of 3 or 4 vertices in XYZ coordinates. My program (or at least the intention) will go through each face, map a texture image onto the face, and save the picture. I can handle the latter two parts, but I'm having trouble mapping the face onto a 2D surface. I don't have access to the normals, which I believe helps. (The vertices of quads will always lie in the same plane, so quads won't be "bent").

[image: Face in 3D space]

to

[image: Face in 2D space]

Potential solutions I've thought about (but have no clue how to implement):

1. Using 2 vertices, calculate the angular deviation from an axis (e.g. using the top 2 vertices of a quad to calculate the rotation Y). [image: Using delta X and delta Y to calculate rotation Y] After doing this for all three axis, I can then rotate the vertices the opposite rotations to hopefully make it flat (I don't know how to do that mathematically). However, the issue I see with this solution is that an x coordinate can be changed by 2 rotations (y and z), not just 1 (and same goes with y and z coordinates).
2. Instead of rotating the face, I recreate the shape. Like in solution 1, I use two vertices. Instead of calculating the rotation, I calculate the length and slope of the ege. I can then draw that same line in 2D space and repeat for the other edges. I find the slopes of the edges so I can get the angles on the intersecting edges correct (think polar coordinates). I have an idea on how to do this, but I'm not sure it's the best solution.

Code answers are accepted but not required, I guess. (VB, C#, JS, whatever your preference) I'd like to know the math behind what I'm doing as well. Thorough explanations are encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to calculate a rotation that maps the face normal to `(0, 0, 1)`. Applying that rotation to the face will make it lie in the xy plane.

To calculate the face normal, take any three points `p1, p2, p3` and compute

```
n = normalize((p2 - p1) x (p3 - p1)),
```

where `x` is the cross product.

Then, the rotation axis is:

```
rotAxis = n x (0, 0, 1) = (ny, -nx, 0)
```

The rotation angle is:

```
cos rotAngle = n * (0, 0, 1) = nz
sin rotAngle = sqrt(1 - nz * nz)
```

Once you have this, you can apply the rotation to the face (e.g., by [converting the rotation to a rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)). Then, simply drop the z-coordinate.

At the end, you can also perform 2D transforms like translations and a 2D rotation as you like.

Answer (score 1):

To get 2D coordinates for the points on a face, you need two orthogonal unit vectors in the same plane.  Let's call them **u** and **v**.  Then for each 3D point **p** in the plane, its 2D coordinates are **(u.v, v.p)**, where '.' is the dot product.

First calculate a normal to the surface.  A cross-product of any two vectors in the plane will do.  You might want to go around and add up the cross products of each angle in the face to average out any errors.  Normalize the length of the normal to 1 and call it **n**.

Now we need an arbitrary vector that is orthogonal to the normal.  Pick the axis with the smallest coordinate in **n**, make a unit vector **x** along that axis, remove its component along **n** (i.e., **x -= n*(x.n)**) and normalize its length to get **u**.

Then just take the cross product of **n** and **u** to get **v**.